# string’ does not name a type error and name_ pointer

Tags: c++

I am working on a C++ program. In the `main()` function, it will ask the user to input the first and last names of their friends, and the hobbies they have. For example, the user input will be like this:

### Input

```
Erik,French,soccer,END
Jenna,Obrien,soccer,games,END
Ricardo,Waters,games,baseball,END
```

Which will then output the list of users and the top 5 interests ranked by the number of users who have those interests, like this:

### Output

```
The Users
==============================

Erik French
Jenna Obrien
Ricardo Waters

The Top 5 Hobby Metrics
==============================

Rank Hobby Count
============================
1 soccer 2
2 games 2
3 baseball 1
```

When I run the program, I get these errors:

[image: errors]

I tried to rename the string reference to stdin, but it then says

> 'stdin’ does not name a type

I also don't understand why the program wants me to rename the `name` pointer to `name_`  when the `name_` pointer is already initialized in the constructor.

Here is my code:

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "User.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<User> users;
    vector<string> allHobbies;

    string firstname, lastname, hobby;
    while (cin >> firstname >> lastname) {
        string friendsname = firstname + " " + lastname;
        User user(friendsname);

        while (cin >> hobby && hobby != "END") {
            user.AddHobby(hobby);
            allHobbies.push_back(hobby);
        }

        users.push_back(user);
    }

    // Print users
    cout << "The Users" << endl;
    cout << "=========================" << endl;
    for (const auto& user : users) {
        cout << user.GetName() << endl;
    }

    // Count hobby occurrences
    sort(allHobbies.begin(), allHobbies.end());
    auto last = unique(allHobbies.begin(), allHobbies.end());
    vector<pair<string, int>> hobbyCounts;
    for (auto it = allHobbies.begin(); it != last; ++it) {
        hobbyCounts.push_back(make_pair(*it, count(allHobbies.begin(), allHobbies.end(), *it)));
    }

    // Sort by count and print top 5
    sort(hobbyCounts.begin(), hobbyCounts.end(), [](const auto& p1, const auto& p2) {
        return p1.second > p2.second;
    });

    cout << "The Top 5 Hobby Metrics" << endl;
    cout << "=========================" << endl;
    cout << "Rank\tHobby\tCount" << endl;
    cout << "=========================" << endl;
    int i = 1;
    for (const auto& p : hobbyCounts) {
        if (i > 5) break;
        cout << i++ << "\t" << p.first << "\t" << p.second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

User.h

```cpp
#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class User {
public:
    User(const std::string& name);
    void setName(std::string);
    const std::string& GetName() const;
    void AddHobby(const std::string& hobby);
    const std::vector<std::string>& GetHobbies() const;
    void printInfo() const;

private:
    std::string name_;
    std::vector<std::string> hobbies_;
};

#endif
```

User.cpp

```cpp
#include "User.h"
#include <iostream>

// Constructor
User::User(const std::string& name) {
    this->name_ = name;
}

// Getters
std::string User::GetName() const {
    return name;
}

// Setters
void User::setName(std::string name) {
    this->name = name;
}

// Other methods
void User::printInfo() const {
    std::cout << "Name: " << name_ << std::endl;
}
```

Hobby.h

```cpp
#ifndef HOBBY_H
#define HOBBY_H

#include <string>

class Hobby {
private:
    std::string name_;
public:
    Hobby();
    Hobby(const std::string& name);
    const std::string& GetName() const;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Advice -- please properly indent your code.  Every line is flushed to the left, making the code hard to read.

Comment: fix all the other errors. you have name where you mean name_ . You are missing constr of the defintion of GetName. WHen I fix those this code compiles

Comment: take out using namespace std, this can cause all sorts of odd errors by dropping random names into scope

Comment: The code in the error image doesn't appear to match the code in the question... (missing `std::` in the image)

Comment: Please see [mre]. There is so much code that this question has at best a slim chance of being helpful to someone else in the future. A syntax error rarely requires more than half a dozen lines to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a typo, the class member is `name_` rather than `name`.

```
// Getters
std::string User::GetName() const {
    return name_;
}

// Setters
void User::setName(std::string name) {
    this->name_ = name;
}
```

Another problem is that you have this declaration in User.h:

```
const std::string& GetName() const;
```

But it's different from its definition in User.cpp, which is:

```
std::string User::GetName() const;
```